# Dictionary doesn't allow List as Key but is allows custom object as Key (Considering Object variables can be modified similar to List value)

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, object

I created a custom class `Node` and was able to successfully add an instance of it as dictionary Key.

```
#This code works 
class Node:
    def __init__(self,dataval=None):
        self.val = dataval
        self.nextval = None

NodeA = Node(10)
dictNodeA = {NodeA:'ten'}
#This code works
```

But when I tried adding List as Key, it gave error.

```
listA = [10]
dictListA = {listA:'ten'}
##TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I want to understand the reason for this difference, as both the object and list are mutable. So why it doesn't work in case of list but works in case of object.

Comment: [This](https://realpython.com/lessons/immutable-vs-hashable/) might help. `Node` has a `__hash__` method but a list does not.

Comment: The hash-ability of your custom class **is your responsibility**. Currently, it is inheriting `__eq__` and `__hash__` from `object` which work based on object *identity* so the mutability isn't relevant. `list` objects hash/eq work based on the values in the list, so mutating those values would matter

Comment: @Henry huh? `list` definitely has a `__hash__` method

Comment: While it technically has a `__hash__` member, `[1].__hash__ is None` and not `callable()`